# What is the minimum specification which justifies the name Content Management System?

Tags: content-management-system, opencms

I've written some simple software which helps me manage and disseminate engineering data on a company intranet. It's pretty flexible about adapting to new content and I wonder if it justifies the description 'Content Management System.

A previous question: [how to define content management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215297/how-to-define-content-management) did a pretty good job of defining a CMS, but I've a feeling my approach fails to reach the bar.

What is the minimum set of features considered essential in a Content Management System, and are there names for subsets of these features?

For example, I've seen some software described as a 'dashboard'. Is this a subset of a CMS?

I'm not really interested in testimonials for other CMS solutions.

Comment: Does it manage content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit like Jazz, if you have to ask it's ain't ...

To my mind discussions about such terminology tend to be in the Marketing space. If your software is doing something useful, who cares what it is, or more to the point what label you put on the tin?

Comment: I think it is still important to market your software a little - and do it correctly. For example, I haven't written a book about my open-source project, nor made any ads, but at least I describe it correctly. It's a blogging program - what if I marketed it as a disk defragmenter? People would be very disappointed.  I do agree with your first point, though.

Comment: Yes, you're right. From what you described your system does sound like a Content Management system to me. I wouldn't agonise too much over the finest detail of function.

Comment: Well, I've no intention of marketing it, so that aspect is unimportant. My concern was that if I released it to the public (distinct possibility) and I described it as a CMS, would people expect features I haven't bothered to provide.

Comment: LESS of a distinct possibility, now. I've become disillusioned with the idea of spreading the word about what it does, mostly because I've made it fairly essential at work ... *but no-one realises that*

Answer (score 0):

Came across a simple definition from a text from what you could possible consider an 'other CMS solution', but we web-frameworkers tend to have bizarre views on CMSs.

> Content management systems (CMS)
>   let users create and edit pages on a
>   site dynamically through a web-based
>   interface. Sometimes called
>   *brochureware* site because they tend to be used in the same fashion as
>   traditional printed brochers handed
>   out by businesses.

*Practical Django Projects, 1st ed.* James Bennetts
http://www.apress.com/book/preview/9781590599969

Not the final answer, but one definition.

Comment: Well, as I said in the question, I'm not really interested in testimonials for other CMSs. I don't have to compare my system with others, I was just curious whether I could describe it as a CMS to the people who use it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to look at it. What is the name: "Content Management System". You could argue that if it is a system to manage content, it's a content management system (small letters). The other way to look at is user expectation. What does a test group of representative users or developers in your target audience expect when they hear CMS? Editing the textual content of a website comes to mind in this case.

If you want to provide a description useful to a broader audience, you have to understand their expectations. If your own interpretation is that those expectations would be unfulfilled, you might come up with a more specific label. Perhaps Engineering Data Management System, or something more specific to your purpose. I think you will be much happier with this.

Lastly, if you need to categorize it on some form of public resource website, you might have to go up or laterally from an existing CMS category. Or, use the category, but a more specific label for the product itself.

Comment: The users of this particular piece of software fall into the 'what button do I push?' category. They wouldn't know a CMS from a bar of soap. They might understand 'system for managing content', once I explain it to them. I try to provide an easier way of browsing company data, but they normally expect to have to drill down in My Computer, saying 'it was around here, somewhere.' I'm thinking of deleting this question: it has been difficult to explain, and it's used as a means of chipping away at my rep points, even now.

Comment: I am not sure what your comment regarding the chipping away of rep points means. I see no up-votes on any answers. That makes it hard to judge what direction of answers you liked best.